# Calculating Average, Finding Min/Max in Marie Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, binary, marie

I'm trying to figure out a way to store the min and max of 10 numbers that are input by the user. I'm not searching through an array of numbers but rather I want to compare each input number that comes in before I add it to the other numbers. The code I made below will add all the input numbers together and then subtract to get the average, but I also want to output the min and max, and I'm not sure how to do that.

The numbers that will be input are: 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100.

So currently the code only outputs the average which is 55

```
ORG 100

LOOP, LOAD X    /counter
SUBT TEN
SKIPCOND 000   /if X = 10
JUMP LOOP2     /take average after X = 10;

CLEAR           /BEGIN INPUTING NUMBERS FOR AVERAGE
INPUT
ADD Y           /add Y to the input
STORE Y         /save new value
CLEAR
LOAD X         /INCREMENT COUNTER
ADD ONE
STORE X
CLEAR
JUMP LOOP       /RESTART LOOP

LOOP2, LOAD Y    /LOAD ALL THE ADDED NUMBERS
SKIPCOND 800     /WHEN Y = 0
JUMP PRINT       /GO TO OUTPUT

SUBT TEN         /SUBTRACT 10 UNTIL REACH 0
STORE Y          /STORE NEW NUMBER
CLEAR
LOAD AVERAGE     /EACH LOOP ADD 1 TO AVERAGE
ADD ONE
STORE AVERAGE
CLEAR
JUMP LOOP2

PRINT, LOAD AVERAGE
OUTPUT

HALT

TEN, DEC 10
ONE, DEC 1
X, DEC 0          /USE TO INPUT 10 NUMBERS, COUNTER
Y, DEC 0          /ALL NUMBERS INPUT ADDED 
MIN, DEC 0       
MAX, DEC 0
AVERAGE, DEC 0    /AVERAGE OF Y DIVIDED BY X
```

Comment: Instead of adding the answer to your question, why don't you post it as an answer and accept it? You can post answers to your own questions on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is taken from the [OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34329803/3956566). (it's been edited out)

```
LOOP, LOAD X
    SUBT TEN
    SKIPCOND 000   /if X = 10
    JUMP LOOP2     /take average after X = 10;

    CLEAR           /BEGIN INPUTING NUMBERS FOR AVERAGE
    INPUT
    STORE TEMP
    CLEAR

IF, LOAD X
    SUBT 1
    SKIPCOND 800
    JUMP STOREFIRST

    CLEAR
    LOAD TEMP
    SUBT MIN
    SKIPCOND 000
    JUMP FINDMAX

ELSE, SKIPCOND 800
    JUMP FINDMIN

    CONTINUE, CLEAR
    LOAD TEMP
    ADD Y           /add Y to the input
    STORE Y         /save new value
    CLEAR
    LOAD X         /INCREMENT COUNTER
    ADD ONE
    STORE X
    CLEAR
    JUMP LOOP       /RESTART LOOP

    FINDMAX, CLEAR
    LOAD TEMP
    STORE MAX
    JUMP CONTINUE

    FINDMIN, CLEAR
    LOAD TEMP
    STORE MIN
    JUMP CONTINUE

STOREFIRST, LOAD TEMP
    STORE MIN
    STORE MAX
    JUMP CONTINUE

LOOP2, LOAD Y    /LOAD ALL THE ADDED NUMBERS
    SKIPCOND 800     /WHEN Y = 0
    JUMP PRINT       /GO TO OUTPUT

    SUBT TEN         /SUBTRACT 10 UNTIL REACH 0
    STORE Y          /STORE NEW NUMBER
    CLEAR
    LOAD AVERAGE     /EACH LOOP ADD 1 TO AVERAGE
    ADD ONE
    STORE AVERAGE
    CLEAR
    JUMP LOOP2

    PRINT, LOAD AVERAGE
    OUTPUT
    CLEAR
    LOAD MIN
    OUTPUT
    CLEAR
    LOAD MAX
    OUTPUT
    CLEAR

    HALT

TEN, DEC 10
ONE, DEC 1
X, DEC 0          /USE TO INPUT 10 NUMBERS, COUNTER
Y, DEC 0          /ALL NUMBERS INPUT ADDED 
MIN, DEC 0       
MAX, DEC 0
TEMP, DEC 0
AVERAGE, DEC 0    /AVERAGE OF Y DIVIDED BY X
```